# Statement is Artin Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

There is one excersise given in Algebra by Artin

As

Prove that Hermitian form on complex vector space has orthonormal basis iff it is positive definite

I had read spectural theorem for complex vector which states that every normal operator has orthonormal basis of eigenvector

Now by this theorem above given case already included still i do not why it is essential to be positive definite Because in spectural theorem there is no mention about it

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If there is an ONB $(v_j)_1^n$, then for $v  = \sum a_j v_j$, compute $(v|v)$ directly, and you will see that $(\cdot | \cdot)$ is positive definite.

Conversely, if the form $(\cdot|\cdot)$ is positive definite, then the form is actually an inner product on the space. Given one basis $(v_j)_1^n$, you could perform the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process, and get one ONB.

To get things more clearly, given any basis  $(v_j)_1^n$ of $V$, we could construct a matrix $[(v_j|v_k)]$. Then this matrix $A$ is Hermitian, hence normal. Therefore it is  diagonalizable by some ONB in $\mathbb C^n$. Equivalently we could obtain a basis $(w_j)_1^n$ by translating the ONB of $\mathbb C^n$ back to the vectors in $V$, and the matrix $B = [(w_j|w_k)]$ is diagonal. By scaling the vectors $w_j$, and note that $B $ is still Hermitian hence the diagonal entries are all real, we could obtain a basis $(e_j)_1^n$ s.t. 
$$
[(e_j|e_k)] = \mathrm {diag} (I_p, -I_q, O_{n-p-q}) \quad [p, q \in \mathbb N]. 
$$
Then $(e_j)$ is an ONB iff $p = n, q = 0$, i.e. $(\cdot|\cdot)$ is positive definite.